# Does anyone have a "dark" PyCharm schema file?

Tags: python, themes, pycharm

I'm trying out PyCharm for Django development and I can't stand the white background.  Can someone provide a place to download a schema file? Switching all the colors manually is tedious and time consuming.

Is it possible to use komodo schemas?

Comment: did find this, which was helpful:  http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1154

although not any of these are ported to python, but it is a helpful starting point nonetheless.

Comment: Sadly, the answers below are out of date, because the format of these (nice) color schemes are in XML, and newer versions of PyCharm (I'm using 2016.2.3) use icls-format files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found this wonderful theme :

http://github.com/nek4life/pycharm-twilight

Answer (score 11):

Tomorrow Night has been ported to IntelliJ / PyCharms

https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme

https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme/tree/master/Jetbrains

### [image: Tomorrow Night Theme]

Sorry, screenshot is in Ruby

Comment: The second link has moved here: https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme/tree/master/JetBrains

Comment: I installed the Tomorrow theme and cannot get the color you show.  please show me how.

Answer (score 3):

Here's mine, which was basically copied from the Obsidian theme in Notepad++. This is an XML file you can stick into the `colors` folder in the config. I'm not sure what else you need to do...perhaps just create a new color scheme named Dark, and then copy this data into it.

[Dark Theme](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2973153/Dark.xml)

Comment: cool, i'll try this out for a bit; thanks.
to activate it you simply put it in that colors folder and restart pycharm, then select it in settings under editor->colors&fonts.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those RubyMine themes (http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1154) is the best place to start. There's no import routines available.

If you create some nice schema, please share it.

Answer (score 2):

I made a django color theme for PyCharm. You can get it here: http://www.nerdydork.com/django-color-theme-for-pycharm.html

Answer (score 1):

I have this scheme in both [PyCharm](https://github.com/dashesy/dotfiles/tree/master/pycharm) and [Eclipse](https://github.com/dashesy/dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse). I think it was originally called Oblivion but I further customized it to my taste.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know the last answer was posted 2 years ago, but here you can get my color scheme : https://github.com/romibuzi/pycharm-color-scheme

If it can serve someone

Comment: PyCharm 2.7 ships with a new dark theme called `Darcula` and I love it.

Answer (score 0):

I also did a "Darcula" version of Twilight: https://github.com/jbranc/TwilightDarcula

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text Monokai scheme for PyCharm:
https://github.com/spasserby/PyCharm-monokai

my favorite.